# Finding what intersects feature without join in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, select-by-location

I am new to ArcGIS Pro.

Which Geoprocessing tool do I use to find the Features in FeatureA that intersect FeatureB without prerforming a join?

I just want a selection of FeatureA - not clipped to FeatureB and not altered in any way.

Both Features are polygons.

I'm looking for a select one feature by another feature.

The Intersect Tool seems to create a new feature class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To simply select features which intersect other features, I recommend using the **[Select Layer By Location](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/select-layer-by-location.htm)** geoprocessing tool. This is the same as using the  **[Select By Location](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/select-features-by-location.htm)** tool from within the Map.